# Remove whitespaces in Carousal - SharePoint Online Modern Webpart

Tags: sharepoint, carousel, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

I want to make a carousal or image slider in sharepoint modern webpart. I tried with "Image gallery" webpart.
But for horizontal images (example: height : 50px and width: 400px) , there are a lot of whitespaces above and below the image. I am not able to decrease the webpart height also.

So how to remove the whitespaces in this particular scenario?

Is it possible via Spfx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need customize the CSS based on your desired design.

For example:

[image]
Reduce the blank space between the panels.

[image]